# Contando a quantidade de produtos

Tags: sql

Existe alguma consulta que retorne a quantidade de produtos exemplo tenho 10 celulares, 5 da marca a e 5 da marca b. Desta forma e não da contagem total, se sim como fazer? Contando os mesmos pelo id.

Comment: Detalhe melhor o problema , descrição das tabelas , em todo caso pesquise por COUNT e GROUP BY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos a um exemplo: tenho a seguinte tabela de produtos chamada tb_produtos:

```
create table tb_produtos(
 id int(14) not null auto_increment,
 marca varchar(100),
 tipo varchar(100),
 qtd int not null,
 primary key (id)
 );
```

Inserimos agora alguns produtos para realizarmos nosso exemplo:

```
insert into tb_produtos (marca, tipo, qtd) values ('A', 'CELULAR', 10);
insert into tb_produtos (marca, tipo, qtd) values ('B', 'CELULAR', 15);
insert into tb_produtos (marca, tipo, qtd) values ('A', 'CELULAR', 15);
insert into tb_produtos (marca, tipo, qtd) values ('B', 'CELULAR', 15);
insert into tb_produtos (marca, tipo, qtd) values ('C', 'CELULAR', 45);
insert into tb_produtos (marca, tipo, qtd) values ('A', 'NOTEBOOK', 45);
```

Ao selecionarmos nossa tabela com o comando abaixo teremos as informações conforme imagem:

```
select * from tb_produtos;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero selecionar a quantidade por marca de todos os produtos onde o tipo são 'CELULAR'. Executamos o comando abaixo e teremos resultado conforme imagem:

```
select count(marca) as qtd_por_marca, id, marca, tipo, qtd from tb_produtos where tipo = 'CELULAR'
group by marca;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quero saber somente a quantidade de produtos por marca onde sejam do tipo 'CELULAR' e sejam da marca A e marca B. Executamos o comando abaixo e teremos resultado conforme imagem:

```
select count(marca) as qtd_por_marca, id, marca, tipo, qtd from tb_produtos where tipo = 'CELULAR' AND marca in ('A', 'B')
group by marca;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o count por id teremos o comando/ resultado nas imagens abaixo:

```
select count(id) as qtd_por_marca, id, marca, tipo, qtd from tb_produtos where tipo = 'CELULAR' AND marca in ('A', 'B')
group by marca;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda podemos utilizar o comando **SUM**, para somar a quantidade de produtos que temos em cada marca em nossa consulta, conforme comando e imagem abaixo:

```
select count(id) as qtd_por_marca, id, marca, tipo, SUM(qtd) from tb_produtos where tipo = 'CELULAR' AND marca in ('A', 'B')
group by marca;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O comando **count** como o nome já sugere, é utilizado para contar. Já o **SUM** para somar.
Agora é só adaptar ao seu banco de dados.

Comment: Olá Luiz Fernando, poderia colocar o código SQL em texto também? Pode deixar os resultados com imagem, só coloque o código porque facilita para quem precisa de ajuda.

Comment: Sim com certeza. Não coloquei pra resposta não ficar tão extensa e só o código de criação e os inserts que não estão na resposta. Vou editar, obrigado pela dica1

Comment: estou com uma certa dificuldade de criar um storage procedure, que funcione a sua dica é de grande valia e resolve o problema mais estou com problemas de implementa-la tem como me ajudar ai mostro oq desenvolvi e as tabelas envolvidas :D